# Can't find where to change user on Security Token Service Application

Tags: service-application, managed-account, security-token-service

So right now I'm trying to delete a managed user account in my SharePoint Server farm as we try and make him non-existent, using the following code:


`$s = get-spmanagedaccount "Account_Name"

$s.Delete()`

Getting the following error message:

`Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): "The account is still being used by these components:

security token service application`

Also remove-spmanagedaccount had no better success.

Now I must have looked everywhere for a configuration for the Security Token Service Application but have come up dry.  Central Administration, PowerShell, API, Config Files, even shut down the farm and took a peek in the config database which I know isn't right, but no success.  Anyone have any ideas?

It should be noted that this is the former database access account, that we need to remove.  We already changed everywhere else we can including stsadm -o updatefarmcredentials.

Comment: same issue for me. Did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

It is SP 2010?

Did you tried:

Central Administration > Security > General Security > Configure service accounts > [Select One] Service Application Pool - SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool

or shortcut to it:

http://[CA url]/_admin/FarmCredentialManagement.aspx

Comment: See above comments, but got this error after clicking on link in Central Admin:
Error

Some or all identity references could not be translated.


Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: acorrelationid

Date and Time: 9/20/2011 5:30:06 PM

Comment: http://www.bluedoglimited.com/SharePointThoughts/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=312

Comment: As this is largely experimental for me, I don't want to accept "this can't be done" as an answer. I'm really hoping I can remove a db access account and still have a survivable farm...

Comment: Did you check Application Pools identities directly via IIS Manager? I don't recommend changing them there but just as information.

Comment: tried that as well, set them to my new login, no dice :-(